# special characters after saving draft interpreted as �

Tags: wp-admin, metabox, post-meta, wpalchemy

I am trying to create posts in hindi language. These characters `UÉeÉMÑüqÉÉU` after saving/publishing are interpreted as `U�e�M��q��U`. Though, the special characters are stored with no change in the mysql database. The `�` symbol is only during retrieving.
I'm stuck here. The post editor is modified to intake multiple posts. http://www.farinspace.com/multiple-wordpress-wysiwyg-visual-editors/

I tried commenting these lines in wp-config.php. But none worked.

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'UTF-8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Also, placed `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` in wpdb class constructor of wp-db.php. Negative, even this didn't work

How do i overcome this?

Comment: Don't edit any core files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its utf-8 character encoding problem. Fixed it using the function utf8_encode():

```
utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($mb->get_the_value()));
```

Answer (score 1):

try

`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`

this is what's in my wp-config.php

and remove

`define('DB_CHARSET', 'UTF-8');`

Comment: **[Reference link to WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Database_character_set)**

Comment: Ain't `DB_COLLATE` the one that would deal with this issue?

Comment: @Damien that didn't work!!! I still find ��

Comment: @nuthan I would suspect that existing data in your SQL database is not UTF-8. Have you tried adding new content in Hindi? Also this article might help you http://srinix.wordpress.com/2007/08/29/tutorial-how-to-store-utf8-indian-language-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @Damien the content is stored in wp_postmeta table, meta_value field, collation:utf8_general_ci. I am coping the hindi content from MS-word document. Does this affect in copying the format? I usually copy it to notepad b4 pasting it to the wordpress editor, To avoid MS-word styles.

Comment: Yes nuthan it would as ms word would copy hidden characters and notepad for windows doesnt support UTF8 ... Try a copy of notepad++ and it will probably tell you the character encoding

Comment: well.., am working on ubuntu, I use gedit. And also, i installed this plugin, but still I see no reliable results http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/indic-ime/

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am not using default post editor. The post editor is modified to intake multiple visual editor [wpalchemy Metabox](http://www.farinspace.com/multiple-wordpress-wysiwyg-visual-editors/)
Any ideas to resolve with � characters?

Comment: An odd suggestion ... have you checked your browser language settings are correct? this can lead to funny characters. Sorry Im not a DBA and this might be more of a DB character issue